# Prove that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 3 {25n}$ converges

Tags: limits, convergence-divergence

Just by looking at it's easy for me to say that $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 3 {25n}$ converges. But how can I prove it?

If I try to do it by the fraction criteria ($\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} |\frac {a_n+1} {a_n}|<1)$ I actually end up with $1<1$ what's not supposed to be true. What am I misisng out on?

Comment: You can upper or lower bound that sum by an integral $\int \frac{3}{35t}dt$.

Comment: It doesn't converge!!!

Comment: It doesn't converge.

Comment: I guess that postulating convergence was a fatal error ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:** $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac 3 {25n}=\frac{3}{25}\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n} $ and that is the [Harmonic Series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_series_(mathematics)) which diverges